# JSON decoded array in PHP

Tags: php, json

In Url call i got this type of data. i want to get "coupon_title" value

```
Array ( [success] => 1 
[data] => Array ( 
[0] => Array ( 
[0] => Array ( [featured] => [exclusive] => [promo_id] => P11757 
           [offer_id] => 412 [offer_name] => Flipkart.com CPS - India 
           [coupon_title] => Buy Sony Mobiles along with battery charger and get 20% OFF on battery charger 
           [coupon_type] => Promotion 
           [link] => http://tracking.vcommission.com/aff_c?offer_id=412&aff_id=27655&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.flipkart.com%2Fpromotion%2Fpr%3Foffer%3DMobile_combo_31.g1%26sid%3Dtyy%2C4io%26 
           [coupon_expiry] => 2015-12-31 [added] => 2014-08-26 )
```

Comment: And what's stopping you...?

Comment: $data['data'][0][0]['coupon_title']

Answer (score 0):

```
$coupon_title = $data['data'][0][0]['coupon_title'];
```

Comment: Still not a good idea to answer such trivial questions, especially when you don't even provide any explanation ;)

Answer (score 0):

it must be something like

```
$array['data']['0']['0']['coupon_title']
```

I didn't test but it will be like it.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

pass your array as $mainArray

```
 $res = array();
    array_walk_recursive($mainArray, function($item,$key){
               global $res;
               $res[$key] = $item;
    });
    echo "<pre>".print_r($res)."</pre>";
    echo $res["coupon_title"];
```